# Sum of different sums

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello there community,

I have problems to combine the value of 3 different sum queries.
We have a table with several columns, like: `customer_id, amount_hours, start_date, end_date, one_time`.

There are 3 different categories/conditions to sum them up.

1. one_time is true
2. end_date is NULL and one_time is false
3. end_date is not NULL and one_time is false

I got those 3 queries done. They work perfectly. Now I want to add the results into a single column next to customer_id of course. What the table represents is the amount of "free hours" (sorry, English isn't my native language and I cannot think of a better expression). Either the customer bought a certain amount of that as a one-time payment or it has a contract that adds amount of X hours per month.

Let's say customer random-store has bought 20 hours as one-time payment, paid the whole last year  for 5 hours per month and during this current year has changed it to 8 hours per month. Then it would need to sum 20 + (12months * 5 hours = 60) + (8months {as it is August now} * 8 hours = 64) = 144.

So far I got the 3 queries to get 20, 60 and 64. But if I try something like `select sum ((select sum(....)+select sum(....)+select sum(....))`, then it is not working. I'm getting syntax-erros and I have the feeling that I'm trying something that just isn't how the correct syntax structure should look like, adding the three different sum-queries. Tried googling it, no luck. Could someone help?

1st sum:

```
select sum (amount_hours) from [myTable] where customer_id=100112 AND one_time= 'True'
```

2nd sum:

```
select sum ((datediff(month, Start_Date, End_Date)+1)* amount_hours) from [myTable] where customer_id = 100112 AND one_time = 'False' and end_date is not NULL
```

3rd sum:

```
select sum ((datediff(month, Start_Date, Getdate())+1) * amount_hours) from [myTable] where customer_id = 100112 AND one_time = 'False' and end_date is NULL
```

My samples include a customer_id on purpose. Will do without them and a group by later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.one_time is true
>
> 2.end_date is NULL and one_time is false
>
> 3.end_date is not NULL and one_time is false

No problems.

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN one_time = 'True'
                THEN amount_hours 
                END) sum1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL and one_time = 'False'
                THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, Start_Date, End_Date) + 1) * amount_hours 
                END) sum2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NOT NULL and one_time = 'False'
                THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, Start_Date, Getdate()) + 1) * amount_hours
                END) sum3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY customer_id
```

You may add `ELSE 0` to CASEs if needed.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't explain myself well enough. When I put that in, I get customer_id and then sum1, sum2, sum3 as colums. But only want customer_id and the sum of the other 3 columns. So only 2 columns in total, with one of them being customer_id.

Comment: You can just replace the "sum1," "sum2," by "+" then, to have `customer_id, SUM(...) + SUM(...) + SUM(...)`

Comment: Thanks @Pepper 
In the meantime I have solved it by using one sum(case with
WHEN {condition1}
THEN
WHEN {condition2}
THEN
WHEN {condition3}
THEN

also worked like that. Akina had the logic mixed up with, as the GetDate() should be used if end_date is NULL (not when it is NOT NULL). So my expected results were not matching and I got all confused. Anyhow, both of your answers helped me to get it right. Thanks!!!